# Linq Outer Join on object array

Tags: c#, linq, outer-join

Consider a set of 6 [StringKey,Value] arrays, in pseudo code:

```
object[,2][6] KeyValueArrays; //illustr as array, could also be List<> or Dict<>
```

I would like to convert this into a single table:

```
object[,7] KeyWithUpTo6Values  //outer join of the 6 orig key-value sets
```

If a given key occurs in (say) 3 of the 6 original [Key, Value] arrays, then the joined row for that key will contain 3 values and 3 nulls.

Question: can I do this with LINQ using just simple containers like arrays and generic lists & dictionaries ?

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output

Comment: Using object arrays to store key/value pairs like this is really a missed opportunity to use pretty much any other data structure instead.

Comment: Why `in pseudo code` while your tag is c# ?

Comment: by "pseudo-code" I mean to interpret array loosely - and I take it from the comment below on IEnumerable.  e.g. the data could be arranged into Dictionary<string, struct{string, object}> if that's what LINQ wants -  my question is really about getting a snippet to do joins on a set of key-value lists

Comment: @tpascale to get a snippet, you should show something. Otherwise we will continue to talk at conceptual level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I might be missing something, but the fact that your question mentions *generic lists & dictionaries*, I think that when you say array, you are referring to some king of vector data structure.

So, key-value pairs can be stored using a `Dictionary<T1,T2>`. Let's, for instance, assume that you key is a `string` and a value class `MyValueClass` with a single property of integer type. You data declaration would look like this:

```
class Program
{
    class MyValueClass
    {
        public int Value {get;set;}
    }

    // Other elements elided for clarity

    private Dictionary<string, MyValueClass> data = new Dictionary<string, MyValueClass>();

}
```

Now, you stated that you'd have an N number of these structures which you'd like to do an outer join on. For instance,

```
private Dictionary<string, MyValueClass>[] data = new Dictionary<string, MyValueClass>[6]();
```

The problem here is that the number of "columns" in the **type** of the joined structure depends on this N, but unless you use some other kind of data structure (i.e., a List) to represent your *row*, you will not be able to do this dynamically, i.e., for any N, because data in C# is declared statically.

To illustrate, check the query below, where I assume that the array has a dimension of 4:

```
var query = from d0 in _data[0]
            join d1 in _data[1] on d0.Key equals d1.Key into d1joined
            from d1 in d1joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join d2 in _data[2] on d1.Key equals d2.Key into d2joined
            from d2 in d2joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join d3 in _data[3] on d2.Key equals d3.Key into d3joined
            from d3 in d3joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
                     {
                         d0.Key,
                         D0 = d0.Value,
                         D1 = d1.Value,
                         D2 = d2.Value,
                         D3 = d3.Value,
                      };
```

Don't focus on the joins, I'll explain then later, but check the `select new` operator. See that when Linq assembles this anonymous type, it **must** know the exact number of property -- our columns -- because it's part of the syntax.

So if you want to, you can write a query to do what you ask, but it'll work only for a know value of N. In case that happens to be a sufficient solution, it's actually simple although the example I wrote might be a little over complex. Back to the query above, you'll see a repeated pattern of *from / join / from DefaultIfEmpty*. This pattern was copied from [here](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/OuterJoinSample.ashx), and it works actually simply: it joins two structures by some key into another resulting structure (the `into dnjoined` above). Linq will process all records on the left list, and for each of those, it will process every record of the right list (a Cartesian plan of N1 x N2), like this:

```
foreach (var d0 in _data[0])
{
    foreach (var d1 in _data[1])
    {
        if (d0.Key == d1.Key) 
        {
            // Produces an anonymous structure of { d0.Key, d0.Value, d1.Value }
            // and returns it.
        }
    }
}
```

So, a **inner join** operation is the same as combining every row and then selecting the ones where the keys match. The **outer join** differs by producing a row even when the key doesn't match, so in our pseudo-code, it would be something like:

```
foreach (var d0 in _data[0])
{
    foreach (var d1 in _data[1])
    {
        if (d0.Key == d1.Key) 
        {
            // Produces an anonymous structure of { d0.Key, d0.Value, d1.Value }
            // and returns it.
        }
        else
        {
            // Produce a anonymous structure of {d0.Key, d0.Value, null}
        }     
    }
}
```

The else block is achieved in the LINQ code before by adding a second `where` clause, which asks for rows even when there is no match, which is a empty list that can return data when DefaultIfEmpty is called. (again, see the link above to get more info)

I'll copy below a full example that uses the data structure and the linq query that I mention above. Hopefully, it's self explanatory:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestZone
{
    class Example
    {
        #region Types
        class MyValue
        {
            public int Value { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("MyValue(Value = {0})", Value);
            }
        }
        #endregion // Types

        #region Constants
        /// <summary>
        /// Our N
        /// </summary>
        private const int NumberOfArrays = 4;

        /// <summary>
        /// How many rows per dictionary
        /// </summary>
        private const int NumberOfRows = 10; 
        #endregion // Constants

        #region Fields
        private Dictionary<string, MyValue>[] _data = new Dictionary<string, MyValue>[NumberOfArrays]; 
        #endregion // Fields

        #region Constructor
        public Example()
        {
            for (var index = 0; index < _data.Length; index++)
            {
                _data[index] = new Dictionary<string, MyValue>(NumberOfRows);
            }
        } 
        #endregion // Constructor

        public void GenerateRandomData()
        {
            var rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

            foreach (var dict in _data)
            {
                // Add a number of rows
                for (var i = 0; i < NumberOfRows; i++)
                {
                    var integer = rand.Next(10);    // We use a value of 10 so we have many collisions.
                    dict["ValueOf" + integer] = new MyValue { Value = integer };
                }
            }
        }

        public void OuterJoin()
        {
            // To get the outer join, we have to know the expected N before hand, as this example will show.
            // Do multiple joins
            var query = from d0 in _data[0]
                        join d1 in _data[1] on d0.Key equals d1.Key into d1joined
                        from d1 in d1joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join d2 in _data[2] on d1.Key equals d2.Key into d2joined
                        from d2 in d2joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join d3 in _data[3] on d2.Key equals d3.Key into d3joined
                        from d3 in d3joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                                   {
                                       d0.Key,
                                       D0 = d0.Value,
                                       D1 = d1.Value,
                                       D2 = d2.Value,
                                       D3 = d3.Value,
                                   };

            foreach (var q in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(q);
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {

        public static void Main()
        {
            var m = new Example();
            m.GenerateRandomData();
            m.OuterJoin();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's very helpful ... I can live with a known N solution for now

Answer (score 0):

Multi-dimensional arrays do not implement `IEnumerable<T>` so you won't be able to use LINQ. Jagged arrays on the other hand, could be manipulated by LINQ.

Comment: This is not true...  (It implements `IEnumerable` but not the typed `IEnumerable<T>`)

Comment: ...And can be cast by easy to `IEnumerable<T>` with `.Cast<T>`

Comment: You would lose the key-value relationship then.

Comment: @KirkWoll: `IEnumerable` will give you `GetEnumerator()` at best. You would have to `Cast<T>` to get anything LINQ-able. Based on the OP, an `IEnumerable<T>` won't cut it either. He's really looking for more of a `Dictionary<T>`